# I download TradingView's technical charting library?

Tags: download, tradingview-api

I'm trying to create a new web project and I want to use the Technical Analysis Charts library, but when I want to download it, I want a public website domain with the phone number that I'm from Iran and in the list of countries. . Not Iran !?

what should I do ?